# How to create retro load file in django

Tags: python, django

```
def create_workflow_status_node_merchant_financing_135_handler(apps, _schema_editor):
    workflow = Workflow.objects.get(name=WorkflowConst.MERCHANT_FINANCING_WORKFLOW)
    WorkflowStatusNode.objects.get_or_create(
        status_node=135, handler=MerchantFinancing135Handler.__name__, workflow=workflow
    )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_workflow_status_node_merchant_financing_135_handler, migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

like this how to create a retroload file in django .for adding data in to database

Comment: What is a retroload file? Are you maybe looking for fixtures? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/initial-data/

Comment: use centralized retroload to add 2-3 datas in to the table this is the question .

Comment: ./manage.py centralized_makeretroloads <app label name>  --name  <retroload name>  this is the command to crete retroload file.

Comment: That command is specific to your Django project. We can't really help you with that.